# "People you may know" on Facebook are only female

Tags: facebook

On Facebook 'People you may know', I have only been suggested females for a year now and I am only suggested to other females. I am a woman and interested in men. I included that in my info. I have tried adding a few men to change that but nothing.

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question seems "how to change the app people you may know". I don't think it's  a good place to ask this question here.

Comment: "People you may know" are the friends of your friends. If your female friends have a lot of female friends, you are suggested females. So, the only solution is: change your friends, and keep the friends with a lot of males.

Comment: @serenesat , the question is how to change the sex of the suggested friends> I do not understand why I am only given the choice of female friends. When I linked Facebook to phone contacts, it only gave me the option to add my female contacts as well as if Facebook filters out males.